# Flatten netstat command output in powershell

Tags: powershell, parsing, windows-10, netstat

I am attempting to use `netstat -bano` and collect the output in PowerShell for some very specific reporting requirements.

I have working regex that should be able to parse this output no problem, but since the output appears on multiple lines, the regex isn't being processed correctly

**here's a screenshot of how it comes out of netstat**

[image: sample output]

desired output is something like this (all on one line):

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1092  RpcSs [svchost.exe]
TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4     Can not obtain ownership information
TCP    0.0.0.0:623            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7404  [LMS.exe]
TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1224  TermService [svchost.exe]
```

the use of tools outside of Windows isn't possible, so I'm confined to common tools.

Using `Get-Process` matching on PID also won't work, as it hides sub process information under svchost and lsass.  `netstat` with a `-b` is perfect because it shows both `svchost.exe` and the process that utilizes the port

I've scoured the internet to find a viable solution but most end in a different resolution

EDIT**here is my final script using input from you guys

```
$data = (netstat -bano |select -skip 4 | Out-String) -replace '(?m)^  (TCP|UDP)', '$1' -replace '\r?\n\s+([^\[])', "`t`$1" -replace '\r?\n\s+\[', "`t[" -split "`n"

[regex]$regex = '(?<protocol>TCP|UDP)\s+(?<address>\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+|\[::\]|\[::1\]):(?<port>\d+).+(?<state>LISTENING|\*:\*)\s+(?<pid>\d+)\s+(?<service>Can not obtain ownership information|\[\w+.exe\]|\w+\s+\[\w+.exe\])'

$output = @()

$data | foreach {
    $_ -match $regex

    $outputobj = @{
        protocol = [string]$matches.protocol
        address = [string]$matches.address -replace '\[::\]','[..]' -replace '\[::1\]','[..1]'
        port = [int]$matches.port
        state = [string]$matches.state -replace "\*:\*",'NA'
        pid = [int]$matches.pid
        service = ([string]$matches.service -replace 'Can not obtain ownership information','[System' -split '.*\[')[1] -replace '\]',''
        subservice = ([string]$matches.service  -replace 'Can not obtain ownership information','' -split '\[.*\]')[0]
    }
    $output += New-Object -TypeName PSobject -Property $outputobj
}
$output |select address,port,protocol,pid,state,service,subservice
```

Comment: Screen shots aren't always helpful; can you redirect the output of `netstat` to a file, and paste the contents into the question as code?

Comment: _I have working regex that should be able to parse this output no problem_. Where is it? Are you using flags like Single Line mode `(?s)`

Comment: from a search of "netstat powershell" https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-NetworkStatistics-66057d71

Comment: I would recommend using the link in Kory's comment, but here... `(netstat -bano) -join "\`n" -split "(?= \w\wP\s+(?:\d+\.|\[::))"|%{$_ -replace "\`n",' ' -replace '\s{2,}',','}|convertfrom-csv`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, your comment seems pretty elegant, but I think it misses some data. at least on my machine.  comparing netstat to your output via shows some missing entries present in netstat output.  but i like the pattern you present.

Comment: @KoryGill You're right, it didn't account for any actual IPv6 addresses (aside from [::]). This does, and works a bit better in general: `(netstat -bano | Select -skip 2) -join "\`n" -split "(?= [TU][CD]P\s+(?:\d+\.|\[\w*:\w*:))"|%{$_.trim() -replace "\`n",' ' -replace '\s{2,}',','}|convertfrom-csv`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, you should make this an answer so this question can bubble up in future searches. Nicely done my friend.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician thanks for putting this together.  the service executable got stripped out of the TCP ports, but added into UDP under the PID column.  I ended up using part of your solution along with that of Ansgar Wiechers in the script.  You guys are awesome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably do something like this:

1. mangle the output into a single string:

   ```
   netstat -bano | Out-String
   ```
2. remove indention of the lines beginning with UDP or TCP to make them distinguishable from the other lines:

   ```
   -replace '(?m)^  (TCP|UDP)', '$1'
   ```
3. join all indented lines that don't begin with a square bracket to the line preceding them:

   ```
   -replace '\r?\n\s+([^\[])', "`t`$1"
   ```
4. join all indented lines that do begin with a square bracket to the line preceding them:

   ```
   -replace '\r?\n\s+\[', "`t["
   ```

Complete statement:

```
(netstat -bano | Out-String) -replace '(?m)^  (TCP|UDP)', '$1' -replace '\r?\n\s+([^\[])', "`t`$1" -replace '\r?\n\s+\[', "`t["
```

Comment: Thank you!  This answer got me the closest.  The only thing i added was to split on newline so that i could take the output and create an object

Answer (score 1):

Building off what TheMadTechnician had, I found a few cases that broke his output. Specifically: netstat sometimes skips columns; when a friendly app name and an executable are both output on separate lines, it breaks CSV formatting. Here's an updated version of his/her code to take those pieces into account:

```
$netstat = (netstat -abn | Select -skip 2) -replace "Address\s{2,}State", "Address,State,Application" -join "`n" `
    -split "(?= [TU][CD]P\s+(?:\d+\.|\[\w*:\w*:))" | % {
        $_.trim() -replace "`n",' ' `
        -replace '\*\:\*', '*:*,' `
        -replace '\s{2,}', ',' `
        -replace '(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),', '$1,$2,$3,$4,$5 '
    } | `
    ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the output of netstat so that it becomes one large multi-line string, then split it on lines that start with whitespace followed by TCP or UDP, followed by an IP address (to remove false positives of an application having a name of 'TCP tracker' or something). Then trim any whitespace from the beginning or end of the line, replace anywhere that there's two or more spaces with a comma, and push the results to `ConvertFrom-Csv` to create objects. From that you could filter, group, or just simply pipe to `Format-Table` to see the results.

```
$Netstat = (netstat -bano | Select -skip 2) -join "`n" -split "(?= [TU][CD]P\s+(?:\d+\.|\[\w*:\w*:))" | 
    ForEach-Object {$_.trim() -replace "`n",' ' -replace '\s{2,}',','} |
    ConvertFrom-Csv
# Filter the results for TCP connections and pipe the results to Format-Table
$Netstat | Where {$_.Proto -eq 'TCP'} | Format-Table
```